# В чем принципиальная разница между std::async (launch) и std::thread?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, асинхронность, c++11

Хотелось знать, есть ли принципиальные отличия/преимущества std::async (c опцией launch) и std::thread? Что лучше использовать и что, возможно, имеет меньшие накладные расходы при создании?

Answer (score 5):

Класс `std::thread` используется для запуска функции в отдельном потоке.

Функция `std::async` также позволяет выполнять функцию в другом потоке + возвращает будущий результат `std::future` и позволяет более гибко настроить процесс многопоточного выполнения (в том числе за счет использования флагов `std::launch::async` и `std::launch::deferred`).

> Что лучше использовать?

Зависит от конкретной ситуаций. В одном случае достаточно использовать `std::thread`, в других - использовать результаты асинхронного вычисления.

> Что, возможно, имеет меньшие накладные расходы при создании?

Думаю, сравнивать `std::async` и `std::thread` в плоскости производительности будет некорректно. `std::async` - это по сути более высокоуровневый API, который в реализации может использовать пул потоков.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но меня не интересует гибкий процесс. Именно поэтому я и указал как в заголовке, так и в вопросе `launch`. В данном вопросе меня интересует только многопоточность. При этом, я не указывал определенную ось. Но если уж на то пошло, то в большей степени интересует `linux`. Хотелось бы большей конкретики: например, в этом случае мы получаем такие плюсы/минусы, а в этом - вот такие.

Comment: Тогда я не совсем понимаю, что вы хотите. `std::async` использует внутри тот же `std::thread` (по крайней мере в gcc).

Comment: Я хочу ответа на поставленный вопрос. И если нет разницы, тогда ответ на вопрос прозвучит `"нет никакой разницы"`. Я же не ставлю в вопрос `"зачем и то и другое"`. Ну а если разница все-таки есть (Вы вот упомянули какой-то пул потоков), то в чем она и в чью, так сказать, пользу. Я не вкладывал в свой вопрос какой-то скрытый смысл и подвох (не нужно их искать и додумывать). Как мой вопрос читается, так я его и понимаю. `P.S.: у меня нет в тегах gcc. А есть c++`